# How to write a function in Jquery and call them

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

Below is my code for a function which is to be called up  on  the oncomplete attribute of a Poll element in PrimeFaces. But it is not compiling.My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
   $.fn.downScroll = function(){
      var psconsole = $('#logArea');
      psconsole.scrollTop(
         psconsole[0].scrollHeight - psconsole.height()
      );
    };
 )( jQuery );
 </script>
```

and the poll component code

```
<p:poll interval="30" listener="#{recentActivityBean.onNodeSelect}"
                update="recentActivityForm:logArea" oncomplete="downScroll();"/>
```

But the above code shows error.Please correct it if there is any syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have incorrect syntax (closing brackets and $ inside function).

Changing your code to this will clear up any syntax problems:

```
(function() {
      $.fn.downScroll = function(){
          var psconsole = $('#logArea');
          psconsole.scrollTop(
              psconsole[0].scrollHeight - psconsole.height());
      };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks.How to call this from a poll component.

Comment: @PraveenV : Also any specific reason to create it as an anonymous function rather than just `function downScroll() {....}` ???

Comment: no.I meant it  to be at the bottom position always with the changing content.Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You've not closed } to your function !